# Sending html files with express

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm making a small website that has a little subscription list that emails people using node and express. Now my issue is I send the users an unsubscribe link whenever they want to unsubscribe.

```
app.get('/unsubscribe',
...
...);
```

Now I want to redirect them to a web page after they have unsubscribed. So it unsubscribes them correctly and emails them letting them know that they have unsubscribed, but I want it to redirect them to the HTML /#/unsubscribe after they want to /unsubscribe. I'm sorry if I'm over complicating it but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I've tried res.sendfile('./public/views/unsubscribe.html');

Also res.sendfile('./public/views/unsubscribe.html', {root: __dirname});

Every time I get redirected it tells me "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/public/views/unsubscribe.html'"

Comment: Judging on how you mentioned that you want to redirect them to `/#/unsubscribe`, is it safe to say you are using AngularJS?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using AngularJS routes for templating, have you tried using `res.render()`? If not, you can do something like:

```
res.render(path.join(__dirname, 'yourfile.html'));
```

You'd need to install the path module as a dependency.

Comment: I tried it out. It unsubscribes them, but it doesn't render the page and gets stuck trying to finish the GET /unsubscribe. In other words, it gets stuck trying to render.

Comment: then there's an issue with your path, are you certain that you're pointing to the file correctly? did you check if the console is printing out an error saying file not found? I think you should triple check that you've set it correctly.

Comment: I have this 

res.render(path.join(__dirname, './public/views/unsubscribe.html'));

and it gets stuck attempting to load in the browser. And the console has not printed out an error.